# Accessing an app with homebutton from lockscreen

Tags: ios

I'm fairly new to developing iphone apps and wondering if it is possible to code an app so that user can access the app with homebutton from lockscreen.

For example multiple-taps or long press etc.
Is it possible? and if it is, how am I supposed to code it?

Comment: No it is not possible. Apps don't have access to home button.

Comment: Is not possibile, but using force touch oh the app icon in the home screen in specific devices, you can preview some contents of it

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. There is no public API to access the home button.